# ASP.NET Linq how to add conditional from / to date filters

Tags: asp.net, sql, linq

Basically what I am trying to achieve is:

- if from date is entered then date >= from date
- if to date is entered then date <= to date
- if both are entered then date >= from date and date <= to date

So on my page I have two date boxes where users can choose a from and to date.  The problem is when I enter for example the below, I get items which actually have a date greater than 05/04/2012, which should not happen.  My from date seems to work but the to date filter never works as it always returns results which are greater than the to date.

```
if (finalApprovedFromDate != DateTime.MinValue)
{
    filteredClaims = filteredClaims.Where(cl => cl.claimStatus.Any(cs => cs.createdDate >= DateTime.Parse("05/03/2012"))).ToList();
}
if (finalApprovedToDate != DateTime.MinValue)
{
    filteredClaims = filteredClaims.Where(cl => cl.claimStatus.Any(cs => cs.createdDate <= DateTime.Parse("05/04/2012"))).ToList();
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It looks like the issue might be in your use of **Any**.  You're filtering for claims that have **any** claim status after 5/3 and **any** claim status before 5/4/2012.  It's hard to say for sure without seeing more of your data.

Comment: but then why am I getting results back for i.e 5/7/2012 if the above is checking for claim Status after 5/3 AND before 5/4

Comment: there are multiple claims statuses for each claim, are there not?  So if a claim had one status on 5/7 (matches the first condition) and another status on 5/3 (matches the second).

Comment: yes there can be multiple statuses for each claim..in the above how could I add a check then createdDate > fromDate and statusId = 5 for example

Comment: Check my answer below, if you're just looking at statusId 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modification to the query per comments.  This will return only claims with a claim status of statusId 5 between 5/3 and 5/4.

```
if (finalApprovedFromDate != DateTime.MinValue)
{
    filteredClaims = filteredClaims.Where(
        cl => cl.claimStatus.Any(
            cs => cs.statusId == 5 cs.createdDate >= DateTime.Parse("05/03/2012")
        )
    ).ToList();
}
if (finalApprovedToDate != DateTime.MinValue)
{
    filteredClaims = filteredClaims.Where(
        cl => cl.claimStatus.Any(
            cs => cs.statusId == 5 && cs.createdDate <= DateTime.Parse("05/04/2012")
        )
    ).ToList();
}
```